# not returning anything from postgresql function?

Tags: postgresql, function

Is it possible for a PostgreSQL plpgsql function to not return anything?  I've created a function, and I don't need it to return anything at all, as it performs a complex SQL query, and inserts the results of that query into another table (SELECT INTO ....).  Thus, I have no need or interest in having the function return any output or value.  Unfortunately, when I try to omit the RETURN clause of the function declaration, I can't create the function.  Is it possible for a PostgreSQL plpgsql function to not return anything?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes - ["If the function is not supposed to return a value, specify void as the return type."](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createfunction.html) and also - ["If you declared the function to return void, a RETURN statement can be used to exit the function early; but do not write an expression following RETURN."](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING).

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't directly answer your question, but I found it interesting that you don't need a `RETURN` clause if you have one or more `OUT` output parameters. That's obviously returning something, but allows you to "omit the RETURN" as you say.

Answer (score -1):

No, it must at least return `null`. From the PostgreSQL [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/plpgsql-trigger.html):

> A trigger function must return either
>   NULL or a record/row value having
>   exactly the structure of the table the
>   trigger was fired for.

Comment: it is perfectly acceptable to return VOID in which instance you don't have to have it return anything.

Comment: A (PL/pgSQL) function can return void, but when the function is used as a trigger function then the function has to return something.